# Full Width Footer Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to make footer full width but its not becoming full with by assigning #footer:100%;

Well, When i make the .container and .wrapper to 100% it become full width but content also become full width. here the image! (with .container and .wrapper to 100% )!

image link: http://i44.tinypic.com/33ysups.jpg
here is footer.php

```
    <?php wp_footer();?>

    <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_left">
        <h3>text here</h3>
        <ul>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-left');?>              
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_left">
        <h3>Weitere Informationen:</h3>
        <ul>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-mid');?>  
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="footer_right">
        <h3>text here</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/newsletter.png" alt="newsletter" width="16px" height="16px" />Newsletter</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width="16px" height="16px" />Facebook</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" width="16px" height="16px" />Twitter</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/googleplus.png" alt="googleplus" width="16px" height="16px" />Google +</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**here is style.css**

```
* {margin:0px; padding:0px;}
img { border:none; outline: none;}
ul,li {list-style:none;}
body {background: url(images/bg.png) repeat;}
h2 { font-family:Arial; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; color: #95cd32;}
h4 { font-family:Arial; font-size:16px; font-weight: normal; color:#b400b4;}
h3 {font-family:Arial; color:#b400b4; font-size:16px; margin:15px;}
a { font-family:Arial; text-decoration: none; }


@font-face {
    font-family: 'JellykaCuttyCupcakes';
    src: url('fonts/Jellyka CuttyCupcakes.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'HarabaraHand';
    src: url('fonts/HarabaraHand.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


.container {width:902px; height: auto;  margin:0 auto;}
.wrapper {width:902px; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;}
.logo {width:902px; height:140px; top: 12px;}
.logo img {}
.logo h1 {font-size:42px; margin:0; margin-left:20px; padding:0px 0 0 20px; background: url(images/header_logo.jpg) 0% 50% no-repeat; text-indent:-9999px;}
.logo a {text-decoration: none; margin:0; padding:0px; display:inline; }
.logo span {margin-left:20px; font-size:22px; color: #8D8D8D;}

/*****************************************************************************************
**************************** menu ******************************/

#nav { width:100%; height:54px; background-color: #ffffff; }
#nav ul{ list-style-type: none; margin-bottom: 5px; padding-top:10px; z-index:500;}
#nav ul ul {padding:2px;}
#nav ul ul li a {background:#A1D34C; color:#fff;}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {background:#AF00BD; color:#fff;}
#nav ul li{ display: inline; float:left; margin-right:0px; padding:0; position:relative;}

#nav ul li:hover>a { cursor: pointer; color:#A1D34C; }
#nav li li>a:hover { background:#B301B7;}
.menu-main-menu-container ul li+li {border-left:2px solid #b000b1;}

ul.sub-menu{ width:200px;  height:auto; position:absolute; top:35px; display:none; }

.menu-main-menu-container ul li a {text-decoration:none; font-size:18px; color:#b000b1; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 32px; display:block;}

#nav li ul{ position:absolute; width:200px; display:none; top:100%; left:0;  }
#nav li:hover ul{   display:block;}
#nav li li{ border-left:0;}

.sub-menu li{   float:left;      width:100%;    border-bottom:1px solid #B401B2;}
.sub-menu li:last-child{border:none!important;} 
ul.sub-menu li a:hover{ background:#95cd32!important;   }


.banner{ width:100%; height:330px; margin:20px 0px 15px; background:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
.banner img {width:100%; height:330px;}

#cat { padding:12px 7px 6px; margin-right:10px;  font-size:18px; border:none; background:#fff; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0; border-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0; width:150px; }

/*****************************************************************************
**************************************** Search *******************************************/
#search {height:40px; background-color: #f9f9f9; padding:15px 10px; }
#search input[type=text],input[type=submit] { width:445px; margin-right:10px; padding:10px 15px 7px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000; border:none; background:#fff; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0; border-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0; } 
input[type=submit] {background:#a2d34d; color:#fff; width:auto;  margin-top:0px!important; }


.ssingle {width:610px;margin:0px 5px 20px 0px;height:100%;color:#666;font: 13px Arial;background:#f9f9f9 url(images/title.png) top repeat-x;padding:5px; border:1px solid #dadaaa;}
.ssingle  h2 {margin: 0px 0 0px 0;padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;text-align: left;font: 24px Arial;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden; }
.ssingle  h2 a, .ssingle  h2 a:link, .ssingle  h2 a:visited  {color:#B401B2; background-color: transparent;}
.ssingle  h2 a:hover  {color: #228fc4;background-color: transparent;}   
#single_post_head .post-thumb img{ max-width:250px;}
.title{margin: 0 0 0 0px;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
h2.pagetitle {padding:0px; margin:0 0 15px; font-size:30px;text-align:center;color:#A3D34C;font-family:Arial; text-shadow:1px 3px 10px #CCCCCC;}
h2.pagetitle a {color:#507409;}
.cover {    margin:0 0;padding: 0px 10px ;} 
.entry { margin:0 0;    padding: 0px 0px ;}
.entry a:link, .entry a:visited {   background-color: transparent;}
.entry a:hover {color:#fff;background-color: transparent;text-decoration: none;}
.entry ul, .entry ol{ margin: .4em 0 1em; line-height: 150%;}
.entry ul li, .entry ol li{ list-style-position:outside; margin-left: 1.6em;}
.entry p{font-size:16px; margin:0px 0px 5px;    padding:5px 0px; line-height:22px;}
.singleinfo {font:10px Arial; text-transform:uppercase; color:#B98302; padding:5px 0px;}
.category{ padding:5px 0 5px 5px; }
.category>a:link,.category>a:visited{ color:#F7DB18; }
.category>a:hover{ color:#fff; }

#navigation{ margin:10px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 5px 10px 0px; width:700px; }

     /***********************************content************************************/
#content{ width:100%; height:auto; float: left; margin:20px 0 0 0px;}
#content>h3 {margin-left:25px; font-size:16px; font-family: Arial;}
.content_left{ width:625px; height:auto; float:left; font-family:Arial; margin-left:10px; margin-top: 0px;}
#nach_themen {width:600px; height:auto; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px 5px; margin-bottom:5px; background:#fff; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0; border-radius: 0; border-bottom-left-radius: 0;}
#nach_themen .themen {width:184px; height:auto; border:1px solid #ccc; float:left; margin-left:10px;}
#nach_themen .themen img {width:180px; height:130px; padding:2px;}
#nach_themen .themen h2 {text-transform:uppercase; color:#a3d34c; text-align:center; margin:20px 0 10px;}

.blog_post{width:608px; height:auto; float:left; margin-top: 5px;}
.blog_post img { width:250px; height:auto; float:left; margin: 10px 18px 20px 4px;}
.blog_post.blog_template img{ margin:margin: 10px 10px 20px 10px;}
.blog_post.blog_template .post_content{ margin-right:10px; padding-top:5px;}
.blog_post.blog_template .post_content p{ color:#000;}
.blog_post h2 {margin:4px 0 8px;}
.blog_post ul{ list-style-type:none;}
.blog_post ul li{ width:100%; height:auto; float:left; margin-bottom:30px; border:3px solid #ccc;}

.post_image{width:250px; height:auto; float:left; margin:0 20px 15px 0px;}

.post_content {width:300px; height:auto; float: left;}
.post_content h4 {font-family: Arial; font-size:16px; color:#55247a;}
.post_content h3 {font-weight:normal; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000; margin:8px 0 3px; padding:0;}
.post_content p {font-size:16px; font-family:Arial; line-height:22px; margin:10px 0;}
.post_content span:nth-child(4){font-size:14px; font-family:Arial; width:300px; height:auto; float:left; margin:10px 0 4px; }
.post_content span:nth-child(5){font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial; color:#a3d34c; width:200px; height:auto; float:left; margin:10px 0; }
.post_content .read_more{ display:block; color:#fff; font-family:Arial; font-size:16px;}

.single_post_image{width:250px; font-family:Arial; height:auto; float:left; margin:0 20px 15px 0px;}
.single_post_content{width:335px; font-family:Arial; height:auto; float:right;}


.featured_post {overflow:hidden; float:left; font-family:Arial; /*border:1px solid #ccc;*/ margin-bottom:20px;}
.featured_post h2 {color:#a3d34c; margin:5px 0 15px 0;}
.featured_post img {margin:10px 15px 15px 5px; border:none; float:left;}
.featured_post p {height:auto; float:none; font:18px, font-family:Arial; font-weight:normal; text-align:justify; padding:0 8px 5px;}

.home_post .post_content{ width:auto!important; height:auto; float:none!important; font-family:Arial;   padding: 5px 5px 10px 0;}
.home_post img { width:250px; height:auto; float:left; margin: 4px 30px 0px 0px;}
.home_post.page_single .featured_image{ padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px; height:200px; margin-bottom:10px;}
.home_post.page_single .featured_image img{ width:600px; max-width:600px height:auto; float:left; margin:0; }
.home_post.page_single h2{ color:#B400B4; margin-top:20px; font-family:Arial; margin-left:10px;}
.read_more{ width:34px; height:20px; font-size:28px; margin:0 10px 10px 0; padding:7px 8px 5px; display:block; text-align:center; float:right; background:#a3d34c; color:#fff; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0; border-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0; }


.first_post .post_content{ width:300px; height:auto; float:right; padding: 5px 5px 10px 0;}
.first_post img{ margin:5px 15px 15px 3px!important;}
.first_post  span{ display:none;}
.first_post h2, .read_more{ display:none;}
.first_post .read_more{ display:none !important;}
.first_post h3{ display:none;}
.first_post h4{ display:none;}

.out_post{width:585px; height:auto; float:left; padding:10px 15px; border:1px solid #ccc;}


#single_post_head{ height:auto; float:left; padding-bottom:15px; font-family:Arial, border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px;}
#single_post_head .home_post{ color:#000;}
.single_post{width:100%; height:auto; float:left; font-family:Arial; padding-bottom:15px; border-top:1px solid #ccc;}
.single>h2 {margin:10px 0 15px 0;}
/*.single p{float:left; font:18px, font-family:Arial; text-align:justify; }*/
.single>span {float:left; font:18px, font-family:Arial; width:275px; height:auto; }
#para {font:16px Arial;}
#cus_single h2 {margin:10px 0 20px;}
#cus_single span {float:left; font:18px, font-family:Arial; width:120px; height:auto; }
#cus_single p {float:left;  width:150px; height:auto; }
#cus_single>p:nth-child(2) {float:left; font:18px; font-family:Arial height:auto; min-height:120px; width:220px;}
#course {padding:13px 0 0 0;}
#course>h2{float:left; margin:10px 0; width:230px; font-size: 20px;}
#course>a {float:left; display:block; padding:8px 15px; background:#B2CF39; color:#fff; font-size: 16px; margin-left:70px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0; border-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0;}

#customText {width:885px; height:auto; float:left; margin-bottom:15px;}
#customText h3 {margin:0 0 5px; font-size:16px; }
#customText .textwidget {font-family: Arial; font-size:14px; text-align:justify; word-wrap:break-word; line-height: 24px; }

#custom_social {width:870px; height:auto; margin:20px 0 40px;}

#telefon { float: right; line-height: 22px; margin-top: 2px; width: 305px; }

.single_child {width:100%; height:auto; float:left; padding-bottom:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}

.nothing  { font-size: 15px; background-color:transparent; border: 0px solid; }

/*************************************************************************************
******************************** sidebar **********************************************/
.sidebar{ width:250px; height:auto; float: right; margin:0px 0 0 12px; background:#fff;}
#sidebar_widgets {width:230px; height:auto; float:left; padding:8px 5px; margin-bottom:5px; background:#a3d34c; color:#fff; font-family:Arial; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0; border-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0;}
#sidebar_widgets li {float:left; margin:10px 10px 10px 35px; list-style-image: url(images/list-style.png); font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;}
.sidebar_widgets {width:230px; height:auto; float:left; padding:8px 5px; margin:10px 0px; color:#000; }
#newsletter { font-size:14px; font-family: Arial; width:213px; padding:10px; height:auto; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#newsletter img {float:left; height:40px; width:40px;}
#newsletter h3{text-transform:uppercase; width:140px; color:#55247a; display:block; float:left; padding:0; margin:10px 0 10px 10px;}
#newsletter h3 span {font-family: Arial; font-size:16px; color:#b400b4;}
#newsletter a:link, a:visited, a:hover {font-family: Arial; color:#55247a;}

#facebook { width:213px; padding:10px; height:20px;}
#facebook h3{text-transform:lowercase; font-size:22px; color:#55247a; display:block; float:left; padding:0; margin:10px 11px;}
#facebook h3 span {color:#b400b4;}
#facebook .fb-overlay {position:relative; left:0!important;}

#google { width:213px; padding:10px 10px 0; height:30px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
#google h3{font-size:22px; margin:0 0 2px 0; padding:0; color:#B400B4; display:block; float:left; }
#google span:nth-child(2) {font-size:35px;}
#google>span:nth-child(4) {font-size:25px; font-family:JellykaCuttyCupcakes,HarabaraHand; margin-right:15px; float:right;}
#google img {vertical-align:middle; margin-left:10px;}

.testimonial_slides {height:300px; width:100%;}

.Home_post{width:608px; float:left;}
.Home_post ul{ list-style:none;}
.Home_post ul li{ width:100%; float:left; margin-bottom:30px; border:1px solid #A5A5A5;}
.Home_post img{ width:250px; height:auto; margin:10px 20px 15px 5px;}
.Home_post .post_content{ width:325px; height:auto; float:right;}



 /******************************************footer****************************************/
.footer{width:960px; height:auto; float:left; font-family:arial; padding:0px 0 30px 0px; background:#6e6e6f;}
.footer_left {height:auto; width:35%; margin:10px 0 0 15px; padding:0; float:left; }
.footer_left h3 {color:#fff; margin-bottom:15px; margin-left:0;}
.footer_left a{ width:100%; height:auto; float:left; font-size:14px; margin-bottom:5px;}
.footer_left a:link, a:hover, a:visited {color:#fff;}
.footer_left .menu {list-style:none; margin-left:3px;}
.footer_left .menu li{font-size:18px; margin:4px 0;}

.footer_right {height:auto; width:25%; margin:10px 0 0 15px; padding:0; float:left;}
.footer_right ul { margin-left:17px; padding:0; }
.footer_right img {vertical-align:middle; margin:0 10px 5px 0; height:23px; width:23px;}
.footer_right h3 {color:#fff; margin-bottom:15px; margin-left:15px;}
.footer_right a{ width:100%; height:auto; float:left; font-size:14px;}
.footer_right a:link, a:hover, a:visited {color:#fff;}
.Social_Widget {margin-left:17px;}

.clear {clear:both;}


/* nsu-form */
.nsu-form input[type=text] { width:220px; padding:13px 10px 7px; font-size:18px; color:#fff; border:none; background:#D1D7C8; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0; border-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0; }
.nsu-form p:nth-child(2) {margin:5px 0 0 80px;}
.nsu-form input[type=submit] {background:#b400b4; color:#fff; width:auto; cursor:pointer;}
.nsu-form label {font-family:arial; font-size:22px; color:#55247A; margin-right:10px;}
.nsu-error {margin-left:10px; color:red;}

.sign_up .nsu-signed-up {font-family:tahoma; font-size:20px;}
.sign_up {width:600px; height:auto; padding:0; margin:0; float:left;}
.sign_up h3 {font-family:Arial; font-size:22px; padding:0; margin:5px 0 15px;}
.sign_up img {width:600px; height:200px; margin:5px;}

}
```

any ideas??? why only footer is not becoming full width???

Ps!!!

Comment: if you want a full with ,try to separate footer from your container,otherwise 100% will always be with of your container

Comment: @DanVan, visit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434148/wordpress-full-width-footer-not-working/18434607#comment27085953_18434607) for update, thank you

Comment: Yes Sir, Thank you so much :) This is what i need :) Please Please Tell me how you do this? Please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434148/wordpress-full-width-footer-not-working
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433487/wordpress-full-width-footer  How many times are you asking the same question?

Comment: I got my answer :) Sorry for posting it 3 times

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the footer's content with something that makes it stay in place, without getting the width to 100%.

So I added a footer_content div arround the footer content divs and added this after updating the footer width to 100%:

```
.footer_content{
    width:960px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here is a solution:

http://cdpn.io/gzEBk

Comment: jdfiddle doesn't let it work, dunno why, but try it on a code editor. Try it directly on your project.

Comment: You mean, Just add footer content div and css rules in file directly? or there is anything else i need to add in files?

Comment: You just need to wrap the content of footer (two footer_left and one footer_right) in a footer_content, copy the CSS above to your CSS file and update the footer Width to 100% instead of 960px also in your CSS file ;)

Comment: have you done this in live site? please please show me a snap so that i can be sure it will work with css. also i am going to try your trick.

Comment: Your footer_content is suppost to be 960px, not 100%. Your footer, however must be 100%!

Comment: in Jsfiddle? Or in Code Comment?

Comment: Sir, This is in iframe, I can"t get the codes, Kindly Can you please go to the live site and post solution with site css????? Please...

Comment: You can view the code through the page source code, but here is the pen anyway - http://codepen.io/Gespinha/pen/gzEBk good luck ;)

Comment: You have everything within three divs with a 902px width (inner, container and wrapper). So it is working, but you should leave the footer relative to the body and not a wrapping div. I strongly suggest you separate at least the three main parts of the site to prevent these kinds of issues (header, content, footer).

Comment: Ok How can i separate these divs? By Putting </div> tag in the theme files or is there any way to do this?

Comment: The easiest way to separate them is reading your code and actually dividing it in three portions: header, content and footer. This is a mere suggestion, just to keep your code organised, as this can facilitate the debugging process a lot!

Comment: Can you please add me on skpye? its: davmao.loalm

Comment: I strict my helping to StackOverflow and other online forums, as other people may have the same problems as you are having, if you have any other questions you can always open new posts here on StackOverflow so other people can help too. Please, don't take this personal, just sharing the load ;)

Comment: Okay Sorry, SO i have to separate the three portions to style them separate so that they wont treat as same element by styling. i will try. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It is just a suggestion of a good practice in coding, to solve the problem you just need to isolate the footer, so it is relative to the body and not another div with a hard coded width. Your welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following div below the body tag

```
<div class="footer_background"></div>


.footer_background 
{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
height: 217px;
margin-top: -217px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: hope you have used values for height and background in styles.

Comment: .footer_background
{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height: 300px;
background: #000;
bottom :0;
}

Comment: Please position the div below </body>. Currently it is above the footer.