# Removed header and footers outside of wrap, now having trouble styling logo

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

http://charlestonduilawfirm.com/

A client wanted the header to span the width of the page. It appears I was able to do so partially, but the header background color isn't extending all the way across the page. Also, the logos run outside of the margins of the content-sidebar wrap.

How do I extend the background color all the way across the page as the browser window expands while still locking the header content above the content/sidebar once it reaches a certain width? Normally, I use themes that already have this functionality and am only in the early stages of coding, so I'm at a loss with the CSS here. Here is what I have in my custom CSS file right now.

```
    #header {
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #055792;
    }

    #header .widget-area {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    }

.header-image #title-area, .header-image #title, .header-image #title a {
        height: 110px;
        width: 70%;
        background: url("http://charlestonduilawfirm.com/wp-content/themes/executive/images/logo.png") left no-repeat;
        }
```

Also, here is the functions.php. Is it possible that the full effect isn't registering because of a conflict with my commenting out the custom header?

```
<?php
/** Start the engine */
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/lib/init.php' );

load_child_theme_textdomain( 'executive', apply_filters( 'child_theme_textdomain', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages', 'executive' ) );

/** Child theme (do not remove) */
define( 'CHILD_THEME_NAME', __( 'Executive Theme', 'executive' ) );
define( 'CHILD_THEME_URL', 'http://www.studiopress.com/themes/executive' );

/** Add Viewport meta tag for mobile browsers */
add_action( 'genesis_meta', 'executive_add_viewport_meta_tag' );
function executive_add_viewport_meta_tag() {
    echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>';
}

/** Add support for custom background */
add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );

/** Add support for custom header */
add_theme_support( 'genesis-custom-header', array(
    'width'     => 1140,
    'height'    => 100
) );

/**Remove support for custom header*/
remove_theme_support( 'genesis-custom-header');

/** Sets Content Width */
$content_width = apply_filters( 'content_width', 680, 680, 1020 );

/** Create additional color style options */
add_theme_support( 'genesis-style-selector', array(
    'executive-brown'   =>  __( 'Brown', 'executive' ),
    'executive-green'   =>  __( 'Green', 'executive' ),
    'executive-orange'  =>  __( 'Orange', 'executive' ),
    'executive-purple'  =>  __( 'Purple', 'executive' ),
    'executive-red'     =>  __( 'Red', 'executive' ),
    'executive-teal'    =>  __( 'Teal', 'executive' ),
) );

/** Unregister layout settings */
genesis_unregister_layout( 'content-sidebar-sidebar' );
genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-content-sidebar' );
genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-sidebar-content' );

/** Unregister secondary sidebar */
unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar-alt' );

/** Add new image sizes */
add_image_size( 'featured', 285, 100, TRUE );
add_image_size( 'portfolio', 300, 200, TRUE );
add_image_size( 'slider', 1140, 445, TRUE );

/** Remove the site description */
remove_action( 'genesis_site_description', 'genesis_seo_site_description' );

/** Relocate the post info */
remove_action( 'genesis_before_post_content', 'genesis_post_info' );
add_action( 'genesis_before_post_title', 'genesis_post_info' );

/** Customize the post info function */
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'post_info_filter' );
function post_info_filter($post_info) {
    if (!is_page()) {
        $post_info = '
        <div class=\'date-info\'>' .
            __('posted on', 'executive' ) .
            ' [post_date format="F j, Y" before="<span class=\'date\'>" after="</span>"] ' .
            __('by', 'executive' ) . ' [post_author_posts_link] [post_edit]
        </div>
        <div class="comments">
            [post_comments]
        </div>';
        return $post_info;
    }
}

/** Change the default comment callback */
add_filter( 'genesis_comment_list_args', 'executive_comment_list_args' );
function executive_comment_list_args( $args ) {
    $args['callback'] = 'executive_comment_callback';

    return $args;
}

/** Customize the comment section */
function executive_comment_callback( $comment, $args, $depth ) {

    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>

    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">

        <?php do_action( 'genesis_before_comment' ); ?>

        <div class="comment-header">
            <div class="comment-author vcard">
                <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, $size = $args['avatar_size'] ); ?>
                <?php printf( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">%s:</span>', get_comment_author_link(), apply_filters( 'comment_author_says_text', __( 'says', 'executive' ) ) ); ?>
                <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>"><?php printf( '%1$s ' . __('at', 'executive' ) . ' %2$s', get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() ); ?></a>
                <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'executive' ), g_ent( '&bull; ' ), '' ); ?>
                </div><!-- end .comment-meta -->
            </div><!-- end .comment-author -->          
        </div><!-- end .comment-header -->  

        <div class="comment-content">
            <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
                <p class="alert"><?php echo apply_filters( 'genesis_comment_awaiting_moderation', __( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'executive' ) ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php comment_text(); ?>
        </div><!-- end .comment-content -->

        <div class="reply">
            <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'genesis_after_comment' );

    /** No ending </li> tag because of comment threading */

}

/** Create portfolio custom post type */
add_action( 'init', 'executive_portfolio_post_type' );
function executive_portfolio_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Portfolio', 'executive' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio', 'executive' ),
            ),
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/icons/portfolio.png',
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio' ),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes', 'genesis-seo' ),
        )
    );
}

/** Change the number of portfolio items to be displayed (props Bill Erickson) */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'executive_portfolio_items' );
function executive_portfolio_items( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'portfolio' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '12' );
    }

}

/** Add support for 3-column footer widgets */
add_theme_support( 'genesis-footer-widgets', 3 );

/** Register widget areas **/
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'            => 'home-slider',
    'name'          => __( 'Home - Slider', 'executive' ),
    'description'   => __( 'This is the slider section on the home page.', 'executive' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'            => 'home-top',
    'name'          => __( 'Home - Top', 'executive' ),
    'description'   => __( 'This is the top section of the home page.', 'executive' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'            => 'home-cta',
    'name'          => __( 'Home - Call To Action', 'executive' ),
    'description'   => __( 'This is the call to action section on the home page.', 'executive' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'            => 'home-middle',
    'name'          => __( 'Home - Middle', 'executive' ),
    'description'   => __( 'This is the middle section of the home page.', 'executive' ),
) );

/** Move header and footer outside the wrap */
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'genesis_do_header' );
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' ); 
add_action( 'genesis_after', 'genesis_do_footer' );
```

I figured this would be a common issue but didn't have much success on Google or the search function here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this post, maybe it can help you with the header issues: [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18435028/2714670)

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%;` and also add a color. The current background is an image. Here's the CSS and color you need

```
.header-image #title-area, .header-image #title, .header-image #title a {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background: #055792 url("http://charlestonduilawfirm.com/wp-content/themes/executive/images/logo.png") left no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help. Since I've got you right here on this thread, can you point me in the right direction with regards to the header right widget area? Id like it to display in the header, aligned to the left above the content-sidebar wrap.